# Google Spreadsheets: Sort/filter by background fill

Tags: google-sheets

Microsoft Excel has the handy ability to sort/filter rows/cells by background color. Is it possible on Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: This Google sheets addon does this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sort-by-color/ljeafnadccaobiifhflfhgmbfmdhmanp?hl=en-US

Answer (score 11):

-- Unfortunately, it's not possible to sort/filter rows/cells by their formatting using a built-in function. However, it *is* possible using a custom Google Apps Script like the one [Shannon Chan](https://www.quora.com/profile/Shannon-Chan) lays out [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-filter-by-color-in-Google-Sheets):

> First, you need a way to get the color of the cell. Go to Tools >
>   Script Editor > Create Custom function.
>
> Paste the following code inside a script file and save it:

```
function getHex(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getRange(input);
  var result = cell.getBackground();
  return result
}
```

> This creates a function 'getHex()' within your spreadsheet, which
>   takes in a cell address and returns the hex code of the color of the
>   cell.
>
> Now that we have the function, let's see how it works. To illustrate
>   the function's usage, let's say we have cell 'A1' colored in yellow.
>
> Now go to cell 'B1' and type:
>
> =getHex(cell("address",A1))
>
> This should give you the value "#ffff00" which is the hex code for the
>   color yellow.  (FYI: I used cell("address",A1) so that we can get the
>   string form of the cell reference "A1", which the gethex() function
>   accepts as an argument.)
>
> You can then drag cell B1 down the row, the same way you would drag
>   any other function. This will return the hex code values of the color
>   of all the cells in column A.
>
> From here, you can proceed to filter the cells by color denoted by hex
>   code!
>
> Note: The function getHex() does not dynamically update when the color
>   of the cell changes. To refresh the values, you can delete the cells
>   with the formula equivalent of '=getHex(cell("address",A1)' , and then
>   undo the action with 'cmd + z' or 'ctrl + z'. This should refresh the
>   formulas and the hex results.